# flexbox вертикальное позиционирование

Tags: css, flexbox

Как позиционировать два элемента по вертикали? Пример:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>


.parent {
  width:200px;
  background: #000;
  height: 200px;
}
.child {
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.child:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Если есть возможность, можно и без flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить стили в родительский блок:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width:200px;
  background: #000;
  height: 200px;
}
.child {
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.child:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```